# Range search using solr_query on cql shell

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql, solr4, cql3

We are trying to pull data from cassandra-solr node with date ranges using solr query.

```
e.g.

SELECT *  FROM keyspace_name.table_name where solr_query='{"q":"<col1>:*",,"sort":"col1 asc"}';
            I could find syntax for apache solr documentation to perform range search & examples too.
```

In case of Datastax Solr DSE search syntax for multiple conditions/date filters is not available

https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html

I couldn’t find any documentation for Datastax Solr for following things specifically.

1. 1)“fq” with multiple parameters   2) Syntax for date ranges.
       3)Date    formats & syntax to specify them using solr_query

Please let me know if i can refer to any source other than Datastax Solr documentation for syntax & examples for firing query with parameters

To find data between two dates.

> Equivalent cql query:

```
select * from tableName where startdate >= '1987-19-09 11:14:00+0000' AND  startdate < '2003-10-06 08:42:00+0000' limit 500 allow filtering;
```

**Please help.
 Thanks
Saurabh**

Answer (score 0):

In terms of `fq` with multiple parameters, the official documentation mentions:

`"fq": <filter query expression(s) (string or array of strings)>,`

As of DSE 4.6.10, you can do something like:

`"fq":["a:foo", "b:bar", "c:baz"]`

If you're working with dates, I recommend taking a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates. (Remember that with the DSE Search JSON query format, you may have to do some JSON escaping on top of your Solr special character escaping to get the results you want.)

Answer (score 0):

In Solr, you need to escape special characters with \. Special characters include +, -, &&, ||, !, (, ), ", ~, *, ?, and :.

So your cql query should be:

select * from tableName where solr_query ='{"q":"* : *","fq":{startdate:[1987-19-09T11\\:14\\:00\\+0000 TO 2003-10-06T08\\:42\\:00\\+0000], "sort":"startdate desc"} limit 500;